# Swiper js carousel not working with background image set to background-attachment: fixed

Tags: css, reactjs, swiper.js

I am using [Swiper React](https://swiperjs.com/demos#effect-fade) for my carousel.

- Swiper Version: 6.6.2

I try to create a carousel with fade effect and background images and set the background to `background-attachment: fixed;`.

I need to have a `<div>` element with a background image, inside the `<SwiperSlide>` (because there comes a parallax effect).

I also need the background to be set to: `background-attachment: fixed;`. If I remove `background-attachment: fixed;` it's working fine.

`background-attachment: fixed;` is working fine on the first slide. As soon as you go to second slide it's not detecting the correct position of the image?

See below what I have so far:

https://codesandbox.io/s/swiper-react-background-image-qdwg5

How do I get this to work?